# Remove quotation marks from fputcsv in PHP?

Tags: php, fputcsv

i have array in fputcsv and need output without quotation marks on cells with space. I tried remove with null char, but these are just additional spaces and its not usable solution for me. Any ideas please?

I have this code...

```
fputcsv($handle, array($zbozi['kod_zbozi'], $zbozi['nazev'] ),';');
```

and I receive...

```
123456;"hdd adata"
```

but I want...

```
123456;hdd adata
```

Comment: `$data = [
    1,
    2.5,
    'ABC',
    TRUE,
    NULL,
    '',
    'HELLO WORLD'
];

$t = fopen('./test.csv', 'w');
fputcsv($t, $data);
fclose($t);
` gives `1,2.5,ABC,1,,,"HELLO WORLD"` with no quotes around empty strings, nulls, numbers, even strings without spaces or quotes.... so what exactly is the problem?

Comment: Do you mean that you'd want that output to be `1,2.5,ABC,1,,,HELLO WORLD` without the quotes around `HELLO WORLD`?

Comment: Added explanation to first post...

Comment: Then you'll need to write your own csv writer code, because fputcsv() will always quote string values that contain whitespace characters, newlines, quotes, etc.... you could replace with an `_` or a `.`

Comment: Working like a charm! I just edited fputcsv() function and removed $enclosure from $str ;) perfect! Tahnks for idea!

Answer (score 2):

I created own function from current fputcsv.

```
<?php function vujo_fputcsv($handle, $fields, $delimiter = ',') { if (!is_resource($handle)) {user_error('fputcsv() první parametr musí být data, ale tys mě dal' . gettype($handle) . '!', E_USER_WARNING);
return false;}
$str = '';
foreach ($fields as $cell) {$str .= $cell . $delimiter;}
fputs($handle, substr($str, 0, -1) . "\n");
return strlen($str);} ?>
```